# Make XML builder insert XML from string

Tags: xml, ruby

I have an XML view in a rails app, and need to insert in XML from another file for testing purposes.

I want to say "builder, just stuff this string in blindly, because it's already xml", but I can't see to see anything in the docs that does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I knew I'd figure it out right after posting a question. Using target! is the answer

```
xml.Foo do
  xml.built('build with builder')
  xml.alsobuilt do
    xml.builtinside('built inside')
    xml.target! << my_string_with_xml
  end
end
```

Achieves the results desired.

Comment: +1 All the docs say is "Return the target of the builder" :-(

Comment: The reason this works is that `xml.target!` returns the object where the generated XML is being stored - in most cases, this is simply a string.The `<< my_string_with_xml` then appends your string with XML directly to the output, before allowing Builder to continue.